# Is null-checking on Linq queries idiomatic?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Using Linq-to-SQL, I wonder which is more idiomatic of the following *three*,

- `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar.HasValue && foo.Bar.Value < 42)`
- `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar.Value < 42)`
- `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar < 42)`

The first option generates an extra `Bar IS NOT NULL` predicate that is probably being optimized away in most DBMS'es. If one queried objects instead of a database, the null-check would be mandatory, but since one can create generic `IQueriable<Foo>` queries that might fail on objects but not on databases, the first option would always work, although both the Linq and SQL code is a little longer than the second option. The third option, provided by [Michael Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190338/235908), seems to be the best of both worlds, but will not work in the case `foo.Bar` has type *bool?*: `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar)` (results in a type error as implicit conversion is not made here).

Should one strive to write generic queries that will not fail if used outside of the context they were initially designed for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third option is to use the "lifted" `<` operator, which returns false if either operand is null. This lets you omit the explicit check for null and works for all LINQ providers:

```
foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar < 42)
```

If the compile-time type of `foos` is `IEnumerable<Foo>`, then `foo.Bar < 42` is equivalent to

```
foo.Bar.GetValueOrDefault() < 42 && foo.Bar.HasValue
```

except that `foo.Bar` is accessed only once. (I got this by decompiling the program in Reflector. It's interesting that the compiler chooses to perform the comparison *before* checking for null, but it makes sense as a micro-optimization.)

If the compile-time type of `foos` is `IQueryable<Foo>`, then `foo.Bar < 42` is equivalent to

```
foo.Bar < (int?)42
```

and it's up to the LINQ provider whether and how to check for null values.

---

**UPDATE:** If the type of `foo.Bar` is `bool?` and you only want to include records where `foo.Bar` is true (i.e., neither false nor null), then you can write

```
foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar == true)
```

or

```
foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Comment: Can you show an example implementation of the _lifted_ `<`? I am having trouble trying to understand how it would know if it is `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Aducci: The compiler treats the lambda expression as one or the other based on the compile-time type of `foos`.

Comment: The operator would only see `foo.Bar` and `42` neither of which are `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`. Why would it know the type of `foos` at complile time?

Comment: @Aducci The C# language has already implemented a lifted version of not only every single one of its own operators, but every single user generated operator.  You actually *cannot* implement your own lifted version of any operator because the language will always do it for you.

Comment: @Aducci It's a lambda, and lambdas are one of the very few expressions in C# that are contextual (that is, how that expression is compiled, and what it means, depends on how that expression is used).  If `foos` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, then `Enumerable.Where` will expect a `Func<T, bool>` as the first parameter, which means the lambda will be compiled into that delegate type.  If `foos` is an `IQueryable<T>`, it'll call `Queryable.Where` expecting an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so the lambda will be compiled into an expression encapsulating that delegate type.

Comment: @Aducci So this, in turn, determines whether the compiler is trying to compile that code into a delegate pointing to a method that contains an invocation of the `<` operator, called on an `int?` and an `int`, or if it needs to create an `Expression` representing the invocation of that operator on those two expression (one a property access of a closed over variable, and one a constant integer).

Comment: @Servy - Thank you for the explanation, I didn't actually know what a lifted operator was and I misunderstood the question, I thought `Bar` was a class and Value was an `int`. But in fact `Bar` is a `Nullable<int>`. This approach wouldn't work if it was `foo => foo.Baz.Bar > 42` and the `Baz` property is null

Comment: @Aducci: Yes, that's correct. In C# 6 you can say `foo.Baz?.Bar > 42`.

Comment: @Aducci Although it might possibly work in some future version of C# (post 6.0) if support is added to allow expressions that use the null propagating member access operator.  It would allow one to write C# code with the same semantics as SQL when it comes to null propagation of member accesses.

Comment: @MichaelLiu That operator isn't supported in expressions, so sadly no, it won't be an option in C# 6.0 as something that would work regardless of whether the data source is an `IQueryable` or an `IEnumerable`.  Perhaps in C# 7.0.  (Or even just 6.1)

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for the correction. That limitation is unfortunate.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: When I do `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar)`, it complains that I cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to bool'. I realize that my question was not asked properly - could you revise your answer to reflect on this? Much appreciated!

Comment: @SimonShine: Where did the `< 42` go?

Comment: Well, imagine if Bar were a bool? instead.

Comment: If the type of `foo.Bar` is `bool?` and you want to treat null the same as false, then you can write `foos.Where(foo => foo.Bar.GetValueOrDefault())`. To treat null the same as true, pass `true` as the argument to GetValueOrDefault.

Answer (score 4):

Underlying data storage technology has a way of changing over the years.  Code seems to live on much longer than anyone thought it ever would.  I would not build in assumptions about the underlying storage provider.

If Linq is your abstraction layer, assume any Linq provider might be plugged in at some point in the application's lifecycle.

> The former generates an extra Bar IS NOT NULL predicate that is probably being optimized away in most DBMS'es.

I'm not a database performance expert, but I would think the performance cost for the extra IS NOT NULL will be small compared to the overall cost of many queries.

Comment: Agree - I don't work with Linq enumerations when returning results from the dataservice tiers, I work with List of X

Answer (score 2):

I would write the queries specific to the provider you are using. `Linq-to-objects` may appear similar to `linq-to-sql/entities`, but they behave very differently.

1. They don't support the same functions
2. They don't return the same type
3. They are executed differently

If your linq provider changes in the future, you will most likely have to rewrite your queries anyways. For example, there are provider specific classes like [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) that only work on the given provider. You can't predict what the future provider will support or how it will work.

A simple group by query in linq-to-entities

```
var query = from f in foos
            group f by new { f.Name, f.Bar.Value } into g
            select ...
```

Would result in a much differnt `linq-to-objects` query. Is it beneficial trying to find a query that will satisfy both?

Answer (score 0):

The Linq-to-SQL translator will be responsible for outputting the correct SQL. In this case, your pseudo ORM code reflects the nullable Bar column. This is useful in your application code, when working with returned results, but not so much for the `where` clause of an MS SQL query as per your example. I'd leave it at your 2nd option.